# How can I see whether a commenter has subscribed to be notified of replies / other comments to a post

Tags: comments, notifications

When someone asks a question in the comments, I reply in the comments.

**Is there a way I can see whether the commenter checked the "Notify me of follow-up comments by email" checkbox?**

Can't seem to find something like that, and for the life of me I can no longer even find the "x people subscribed to follow-up comments" or some such, which I am sure (ha!) I have seen before somewhere on the dashboard.

Comment: Are you on wordpress.com?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic. Nope. "Self" hosted. (As in I have full access to everything on a shared hosting account.)

Comment: Is this with the Jetpack plugin?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: that has been activated yes. If need be, I'll do some programming myself (php may not be my forte, but I am a developer).

Comment: It's just Jetpack is the plugin that adds the notification feature, and so this question will probably be deemed off-topic (3rd party plugin) - I'm not familiar with how it stores/handles these user settings.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic: ah, ok, didn't realize it was a JetPack feature. Should be off to webapps then, I guess :)